# How to development in Visual Studio and then deploy apps to Linux machine

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop

How to develop app in Visual Studio and then deploy apps to Linux machine (OS - Ubuntu, web server - Nginx). Can any explain the steps, it will be a great help

Comment: Look into MonoDevelop. That way you bypass VS completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that there are three ways how you can develop apps for Linux using mono.

First is using only Visual Studio for development and from time to time deploy your app to Linux to see potential issues. I personally use this scenario because it's simple and when you are not messing with MS specific stuff or yet fully unsupported things then you shouldn't have problems (at least I didn't so far). Disadvantage is that you will discover mono specific problems only during runtime on Linux machine.

Second approach is using Visual Studio with [Mono Tools](http://www.go-mono.com/monotools/). I tested it when it was in beta and it was sometimes quite handy (you will move the phase of discovering mono specific problems to your dev environment, however you can still have some certain issues on Linux machine), but since this tool doesn't support debugging for now I don't use it personally.

Third approach is to use only [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) on Linux (since debugging is now supported only in Linux). With 2.2 release this IDE becomes really good and suitable for development however I have tested only console and basic ASP.NET MVC apps so I can't tell you if it's ready for bigger projects.

Deployment to Linux is quite easy - I just installed proftpd on Linux machine, configured it and copied project there from Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks tomi

Since you are have been using mono , i would like to ask how the compling process work with mono and how to create package in windowss that can be installed on the linux machine and how to configure the apache to host the asp.net application

Comment: and also thoughts about sharp develop

Comment: If you are developing ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC web app then you don't have to create special packaging procedure, just copy source and other files to your web app folder on Linux machine. Once it's there it's compiled automatically during the first request for the web page. If you want to use Apache, then you will need mod_mono (http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) to run web apps on it. I was using only Nginx as a web server and I didn't tried Apache yet. Same with Sharp Develop - didn't tried it so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an application for Linux in C (as Nginx is)  or C++, you need to develop on Linux.

There are many IDEs for Linux that you can use for this.

You can also try to run Visual Studio in Linux using [Wine](http://winehq.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Windows) on Windows and compile your apps with it , I guess [Apache](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET#ASP.NET_hosting_with_Apache) is only supported ... Disclaimer - I do not have personally experience with it ...

Comment: i have installed the Monodevelop 2.2 which use GTK# , it is very slow as it depends on GTK#.
I was looking for the points for adopting the mono for enterprise app development.