# switching to open source solutions

Tags: asp.net, linux, open-source, mono, monodevelop

I'm a ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio, SQL Server web developer. I would like to switch to equivalent open source solutions. Please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94718/open-source-net-tools

Comment: maybe a bit more info? what part of the stack are you unhappy with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) to get started. You can run all of these on your existing Windows machines, and then later move them to Linux machines if you're satisfied with how well they work for you.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned you should look at Mono and MonoDevelop.

If you are satisfied with ASP.NET MVC, then Mono supports it too. Or you can try open source [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/index.html) form Castle Project.

As for the database backend I would rather suggest [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). For flamewars why that choice look on the net ;)

Comment: I personally prefer PostgreSQL as well, but there's a lot more documentation on using MySQL for newbies, hence my recommendation.

Comment: PostgreSQL is good, however if you want to compare writing stored procedures for Postgre or MySQL, then Postgre is really hell I would say. Also I think that tools for MySQL management are better than those for Postgre.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://www.codeplex.com/ to get an idea of possible open source solutions under .NET

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move to Linux then you should definitely use Mono which fully supports ASP.NET MVC. You will have plenty of choices to replace IIS, for example Apache with mod_mono, Nginx or Lighttpd. Instead of SQL Server you can use mainstream RDBMSs like MySQL or PostgreSQL. And talk about development is here [How to development in Visual Studio and then deploy apps to Linux machine (OS - Ubuntu, web server - Nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056350/).